# JS: trouble with earsing buttons with function

Tags: javascript, function, button

Today i learned how to create and earse objects like buttons with JS.
And then a problem happened.

After shopDraw() (to create buttons) and trying to kill them with shopClose() from another function i get error: "ReferenceError: button1 is not defined". I've tried doing the same from shopDraw() but its returning error too. What am i doing wrong?

If i try to paste code from shopClose() to shopDraw() after alert, it is erasing them easly!

```
function shopDraw() {
                shopOpened=true;
                var br1 = document.createElement('br');
                var br2 = document.createElement('br');
                var br3 = document.createElement('br');

                    var button1 = document.createElement('input');
                    button1.type = 'button';
                if (swordBought===false)  {button1.value = 'Приобрести меч                 '; swordBought=true;}
                else {button1.value='Улучшить меч'}
                button1.addEventListener('click', function() {shop(1)}, false);

                var button2 = document.createElement('input');
                    button2.type = 'button';
                if (armorBought===false)  {button2.value = 'Приобрести броню           '; armorBought=true;}
                else {button2.value='Улучшить броню'}
                button2.addEventListener('click', function() {shop(2)}, false);

                var button3 = document.createElement('input');
                    button3.type = 'button';
                if (bootBought===false)  {button3.value = 'Приобрести сапоги          '; bootBought=true;}
                else {button3.value='Улучшить сапоги'}
                button3.addEventListener('click', function() {shop(3)}, false);


                var button4 = document.createElement('input');
                    button4.type = 'button';
                button4.value='Восстановить здоровье'
                button4.addEventListener('click', function() {shop(4)}, false);


                    document.body.insertBefore(button1, BattleLogger);
                document.body.insertBefore(button2, BattleLogger);
                document.body.insertBefore(br1, button2);
                document.body.insertBefore(button3, BattleLogger); 
                document.body.insertBefore(br2, button3);
                document.body.insertBefore(button4, BattleLogger); 
                document.body.insertBefore(br3, button4);}

function shopClose(){           
            button1.parentNode.removeChild(button1);
            button2.parentNode.removeChild(button2);
            button3.parentNode.removeChild(button3);
            button4.parentNode.removeChild(button4);
            br1.parentNode.removeChild(br1);
            br2.parentNode.removeChild(br2);
            br3.parentNode.removeChild(br3);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a scope issue.

For example, `var button1 = document.createElement('input');` is created inside of `shopDraw()`, so `button1` is only available within that function. In `shopClose()` it is undefined.

You can fix this by declaring the variable outside of the functions:

```
var button1;

function shopDraw() {
    button1 = document.createElement('input');
    ...
}

function shopClose() {
    button1.parentNode.removeChild(button1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Now, to the next problem, but i will try to solve it by myself for some time. Now i know that in order to access variable from every function i must declare it outside of any function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn about scope in JavaScript.

Since you declare `button1` in `shopDraw`, it's only visible within `shopDraw` (and any functions inside of `shopDraw` - that's a concept called "closures").

If you declare `button1`, `button2`, `button3`, `button4`, `br1`, `br2`, and `br3` outside of your functions, it will work fine, e.g.

```
var br1;
var br2;
var br3;
var button1;
var button2;
var button3;

function shopDraw() {
            shopOpened=true;
            br1 = document.createElement('br');
            br2 = document.createElement('br');
            br3 = document.createElement('br');

            button1 = document.createElement('input');
            // etc
```

Note that in the function, I no longer have `var br1 = ...`, but just `br1 = ...`